# How to prevent htaccess from rewriting urls on the redirected page which are the same as the url of the original page?

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

> ### *** NOTE ****
>
> ### Please skip to "Update 9" which is highlighted below for the real question; below was troubleshooting the original issue to find what was really going on.

`*** (Previous title of this question: "After rewriting image url with htaccess, new page shows fine but image from the redirect does not display unless I reload the page?")`

---

A strange thing is occurring, maybe it is a problem with my htaccess code.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysitee\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://mysitee.com/?attachment=$1
```

What this does is change:

```
http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg
```

to this:

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage
```

The code works very well, but a strange thing happens that I need fixed. I am using Wordpress by the way.

The problem is that on the new page, the image on the attachment page I rewrite the url to go to, does not display unless I manually reload the page.

Perhaps it has something to do with the htaccess redirecting too quickly before the http request to display the image could happen?

Here's what happens on the redirect:

[image: the htaccess image loading issue on redirect]

But when I manually press reload on the page, the image loads.

I also did something else, I redirected to the post page after that, and the same thing happens on the post page - all the other images load fine, but the image I redirected from shows as blank until I manually reload the page. So it's not just a problem with the attachment page.

See, here is what happens when I redirect it to the post page the same way:

[image: the htaccess image loading issue on redirect 2]

As you see, the other images and content still loads, just not the image from the image redirect. Again, if I manually reload the page, then the image loads.

It seems like an http request issue as a result of the redirect, or maybe it has to do with asynchronous loading due to the redirect, or maybe even my htaccess code isn't written properly. I can't be sure.

I need it to display the image after the redirect. Please help.

---

**Update -**

here is the html code on redirect when the image is not loading:

```
<div class="attachment">
    <a href="http://mysitee.com/mycategory/myimage/attachment/myimage/#main" rel="attachment">
        <img width="600" height="896" src="http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/myimage.jpg" class="attachment-1200x1200" alt="myimage">
    </a>                        
</div>
```

and here is html code when I refresh the page and the image loads:

```
<div class="attachment">
    <a href="http://mysitee.com/mycategory/myimage/attachment/myimage/#main" rel="attachment">
        <img width="600" height="896" src="http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/myimage.jpg" class="attachment-1200x1200" alt="myimage">
    </a>                        
</div>
```

The code is completely the same which makes me thing it's probably something other than the html code causing the issue.

---

**Update 2 -**

I just compared the entire source code of the webpage before and after reload, and it is 100% identical, not a single character is different.

---

**Update 3 -**

I also viewed the error window under inspect element and there are no page errors displaying. So it must be an internal issue not a front end issue.

---

**Update 4 -**

Okay, here's something interesting. When I right click the image that isn't loading, "copy image" is greyed out but I can still copy the image url which is correct.

[image: the htaccess image loading issue on redirect 3]

does this help?

---

**Update 5 -**

I tried to add:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

to the htaccess, but it had no effect.

---

**Update 6 -**

I used tor to access from an outside ip and different browser, to see if the issue was local, but the issue is not just local, it happens everywhere.

---

**Update 7 -**

Here is something interesting. In the inspection window, I navigated to the image and when I right clicked the image and opened in new tab, it did not open the image but instead it opened the same attachment url. See the screenshot:

[image]

---

**Update 8 -**

Here is the network inspection window:

[image]

I see that it is requesting the attachment url instead of the image url. When I reload the page, it shows the image url where it is currently showing the attachment url in the network inspection window. Could be the problem.

Here is a screenshot of the Network inspection window when I reload the page which loads the image. As you see, it's different. So this is clearly where the problem lies, it is because the htaccess redirect is causing the redirected image on the new page to load from the attachment url instead of the image url until I manually reload the page.

[image]

---

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> ### **UPDATE 9 - (Final Question that needs answered)**
>
> Ok so further debugging confirmed the issue, although I don't know how to fix it. I checked by redirecting to the other URL as well, and the image url is requesting that url instead of the image url just the same.
>
> So what's happening is the same url that is being redirected, htaccess is also rewriting the url for that same image on the new redirected page with the redirect.
>
> For example:
>
> for the image:
>
> ```
> http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg
> ```
>
> which, on page visit is redirected via the htaccess code at the beginning of this question to:
>
> ```
> http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage
> ```
>
> , now, on the page `http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage` which also contains the original image `http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg`,
>
> the htaccess is also rewriting that image `http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg` to the redirected url `http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage`.
>
> So in other words, to simplify into easier terms, let's make:
>   `IMAGE-X` = `http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/myimage.jpg`
>   `URL-Z` = `http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage`
>
> so what is occurring is that whenever `IMAGE-X` is redirected to `URL-Z` via htaccess, every instance of `IMAGE-X` on page `URL-Z` is also rewritten by the htaccess changing the url of `IMAGE-X` to `URL-Z`.
>
> See the path below:
>
> Original URL: `IMAGE-X`
>   1. htaccess redirect causes it to redirect to `URL-Z`
>   2. on page `URL-Z`, it contains the image `IMAGE-X`
>   3. but since it is in the same HTTP request, htaccess also rewrites the URL of `IMAGE-X` in the HTTP request to request the URL of `URL-Z`
>
> ---
>
> Put yet another way, the HTML that the server is seeing is this:
>
> ```
> <div>
>   <a href="#">
>       <img src="http://mysitee.com/?attachment=myimage">
>   </a>                        
> </div>
> ```
>
> But what the server SHOULD be seeing is this:
>
> ```
> <div>
>   <a href="#">
>       <imgsrc="http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/myimage.jpg">
>   </a>                        
> </div>
> ```
>
> So how do I fix the htaccess so that it does not also rewrite the images on the redirected url too?

---

please help thank you

Comment: i did give screenshots. There are no errors in the debug screen, and the html code reads the image url.

Comment: I am updating the question with the site html code.

Comment: i just compared the entire source code of the webpage before and after reload, and it is 100% identical, not a single character is different.

Comment: added more debug info

Comment: even more debug info added

Comment: Do you have chrome?  If you open the network tab in the developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I on windows, then choose Network), then open the page, what's the Status column say for your image?  Anything in the Console tab?

Comment: yes, i have chrome, trying now...

Comment: it is completely empty, says no results captured please reload to capture. posting screenshot.

Comment: Try opening the Network tab before loading your page

Comment: yes, i see. i just did that, posting the new screenshot in a moment..

Comment: done, posted network inspection window screenshot. I see that it is requesting the attachment url instead of the image url. When I reload the page, it shows the image url where it is currently showing the attachment url in the network inspection window. Could be the problem.

Comment: yes it's definitely the problem, the htaccess is causing the page to request the attachment url instead of the image url.

Comment: so what's happening is the same url that is being redirected, htaccess is also rewriting the url for that same image on the new redirected page with the redirect.

Comment: updated question again describing the problem in greater detail.

Comment: added markup to make the question easier to navigate

Comment: i will pay someone to fix this for me...